# Use multiple managed objects context with core data base

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, core-data

I am using core data to store and fetch my data but I am facing some issue. I want to use two thread parallel for following operations:

1. Thread one will insert data in CoreData base table(A).
2. Thread two will fetch data from another table(B).

**How I can do that?**

I did some research on google and they said, we need to use multiple managed object context, But I don't know how we will use that.

Comment: Why do you want to use two threads in parallel?

Comment: A single persistent store coordinator will manage the process of inserting data into table A and fetching data from table B. You do not need two managed object contexts for that to work successfully. You can however create a private thread to manage the persistence process (i.e. saving data) so as not to block the User Interface.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should not access your NSManagedObjectContext on multiple threads. The NSManagedObjectContext created in your AppDelegate should only be accessed on main thread.

It implies, you should create a NSManagedObjectContext for each thread you create. Make sure to set the thread's NSManagedObjectContext's parent context as your main context.

Example : -

```
NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext; // = getMainContext
NSManagedObjectContext *threadContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
threadContext.parentContext = mainContext;
```

and then use threadContext on your thread...

You can continue your UI related fetching on main thread. Or if it is essential to have other thread for it too, create a context for it too.

To know the Core Data concurrency in depth see [a tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-concurrency--cms-22131)

Setting Parent/Child context relationship will merge your thread's Context with main context (it's parent context).

To understand Parent/Child context relationship [check this URL](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/)

Or just under this diagram -

[image: Parent/Child context relationship.]

Credits to the article URL...

Comment: Yes, We need to use multiple managed object context for threads. My concern is that when i will use threadContext for my other threads and then How i will update my main managed object context, Because i read in tutorial, We have to update the main thread context after insert or update the database table from thread context.

Comment: @Mayur Deshmukh How the parent child pattern works when I want to fetch large number of records.

Comment: @RohitKP The fetches happen independent of the parent-child relation. The fetched records stay on the context they were fetched. The changes are merged into the parent context if and when child context is saved. If the explanation is not suitable, you can frame your question with proper detailed problem statement, and tag me in comment, I will try to answer.

Comment: @MayurDeshmukh If I save any object to child, it goes to parent and parent then stores it to persistence  store. In case of fetching object from persistance store should we call fetch on child context?

Comment: @RohitKP That depends on where you want to access the fetched entity object. If you want to access it on the child-context, then yes. Presumably I think you would do that on child context when you want the fetch to happen in background. If you are passing objects from one context to other(that is one thread to other), refer context merging.

Comment: And instead of fragmented questions in comments, its always great to put your problem in a separate question, who knows someone else with same problem as yours may be benefitted....